# Differentiating a matrix product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In one of the books I found that given that for a linear system $x'=Ax$, there exists a matrix $Q:=\int\limits_0^\infty B(t)dt$, where $B(t)=e^{tA^T}e^{tA}$, and $V(x) = x^T Q x$, $\frac{dV(x(t))}{dt}=\frac{dx^T}{dt}Qx+x^T Q\frac{dx}{dt}=x^T A^T Qx+x^T QAx$.

I don't see how the right-most side was obtained. Would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: if  $A = P D P^*$ it becomes much simpler

Comment: @user1952009: Are you assuming diagonalizability here? Because in general, $A$ is not.

Comment: Haven't you given the equation $x'=Ax$?

Comment: Is there some assumption like $\frac{d}{dt}x = Ax$ hidden in here? What's the context? Compare your question to the proof of, e.g. Lemma 3.27 in Control theory for linear systems by Tentelman/Stoorvogel/Hautus.

Comment: @Roland I dont understand why you say that in general a matrix is not diagonalizable. Do you mean with real eigenvalues ? Otherwise, a matrix say with uniformly random coefficients is diagonalizable with probability one...

Comment: @Roland I dont want to enter into polemics. I understand the point of view of control theory. I just said what I say to my students: if you have a (square !) matrix whose coefficients are e;g., issued from measures, you can assume it to be diagonalizable. If you encounter problems, have a closer look.

Comment: @Roland All Right, I have been too talkative. I thought the issue of diagonalizability was relevant because it has been pinpointed in the second remark by yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35425/discussion-between-roland-and-jeanmarie).

Comment: I've made the clarification that this is for the linear system $x'=Ax$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @sequence: Is $x' = \frac{d}{dt}x$? If yes, doesn't this at least show how to get the final equality?

Comment: @Roland: ooops, this is much easier than I thought. I just didn't notice this thing you mentioned... Thank you very much, this question has been resolved.